# Python Selenium 3.4.3 do not raise timeouts, and goes to hung state

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-chromedriver

Using Python 2.7.12, Selenium 3.4.3, Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (32-bit).
While trying to ensure presence of element as follows but no exception is raised when x is not present:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
try:
    WDW(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, x))) 
except Exception e:
    print(e)`

2nd option:

`try:
    we = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x)
except Exception e:
    print(e)`

Is there a issue with the syntax or a logical issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit_wait was set to 10 mins, which caused this behaviour. Reducing the value gave expected results.